# Delay by Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord when starting new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Whenever I start a new activity (even a plain, empty one) inside my app, I see a relatively large delay (1 to 2 seconds). Checking LogCat I see this:

```
// This is a transition from CurrentActivity to NewActivity
03-01 14:59:00.195: I/ActivityManager(515): START {act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT ...} from pid 9382
03-01 14:59:00.242: D/NewActivity(9382): Intent started
03-01 14:59:00.242: D/CurrentActivity(9382): Activity.onPause
03-01 14:59:00.359: D/dalvikvm(515): GC_CONCURRENT freed 824K, 20% free 10419K/12871K, paused 2ms+12ms
03-01 14:59:00.476: I/cat(416): <4>[22335.131317] CPU1: Booted secondary processor
03-01 14:59:00.476: I/cat(416): <6>[22335.138885] Switched to NOHz mode on CPU #1
03-01 14:59:00.742: W/ActivityManager(515): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4131c158 CURRENT-ACTIVITY}
03-01 14:59:01.179: D/dalvikvm(9382): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1562K, 68% free 10961K/33415K, paused 2ms+6ms
03-01 14:59:01.937: D/NewActivity(9382): NewActivity.onCreate
```

Note that everything works OK, no crashes, just this weird delay.
If I put the code from the activity in a `DialogFragment` and show the dialog, it is virtually instant. Only when the code runs in a separate Activity there's this delay.
The code running inside the `CurrentActivity.onPause` is minimal and not resposible for the delay.

Addition: the above is when running under android `API14`. Android 2.2 (API) on a different device shows the same delay but with a slightly different `LogCat`:

```
I/ActivityManager(2473): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cmp=NewActivity }
03-01 15:08:06.537: D/Editor(4591): Activity.onSaveInstanceState
03-01 15:08:06.537: D/Editor(4591): Activity.onPause
03-01 15:08:06.595: V/InputDevice(2473): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
03-01 15:08:07.033: W/ActivityManager(2473): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{CurrentActivity}
03-01 15:08:07.873: D/dalvikvm(4591): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5867 objects / 421464 bytes in 33ms
03-01 15:08:08.720: D/NewActivity(4591): NewActivity.onCreate
```

This is how I create and start the NewActivity:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePickerActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_RESULT_ADD_IMAGE);

The CurrentActivity is too large to post.

Any idea what is causing this and how to prevent it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi, can you show the code of the activity? Bestregards

Comment: Sorry, much too large + spread over three descendant classes. But I have commented out anything that could cause a delay + measured (profiled) all my own code that is related to the activity life cycle.

Comment: Hi, "Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT Display the list of people's phone numbers, allowing the user to browse through them and pick one and return it to the parent activity." maybe to get this list makes the delay in your application. You can see this information here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

pd: this is just what I think, but the delay can occur for another reason. Review your onCreate method and be sure nothing else is consuming resources. BestRegards

Comment: Hi, this is not the phone picker, it is a custom activity - that currently does nothing. The OnCreate is empty (except for setting an empty textview as contentView. If you look in the first logging you see that I emit a D onCreate (first thin in onCreate, before calling suprt onCreate) which is **after** the delay occurred.

Comment: Try removing the Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT flag and be sure this is no the responsible of the delay.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but removing ACTION_GET_CONTENT does not make a difference.